# htaccess redirect www (es) to non www (es)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm currently redirecting all requests for www.example.com to example.com. 
I have this working nicely with this code found elsewhere on stackoverflow:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So far so good.
The problem I have is that I also need to ensure that the Spanish version of my site also redirects — www.example.com/es needs to redirect to example.com/es, but this doesn't work with the code shown above.

What would I need to add to make the redirection work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Odd - it ought to work fine with the code above. That would be covered  by the `(.*)` and `$1`.  Do you have any other rewrite rules?

Comment: As Michael noted, it should work as-is, unless you have something set up like `www.example.com/es` -> `www.es.example.com` or `www.example.es`.

Comment: The Spanish version of your site is in a folder (`/es`)? If so, what happens when the incoming URL holds a different folder:  `www.example.com/anyfolder`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, all helpful. @faa — Yes, I have an /es folder in place. For the multilanguage stuff to work I've remembered I have to have an .htaccess file in there too. I'll try adding the rule to that .htaccess file as well and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention — if the incoming URL holds another folder that exists, yes it resolves correctly. Must be to do with /es having it's own htaccess file. Will report back...

Comment: So after some fiddling, it turns out that adding a slightly modified RewriteRule to the htaccess file in my example.com/es/ folder solved it.
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/es/$1 [L,R=301]` (I can't add this as a solution yet as I don't have a rep on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your example.com/es/ folder, create a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/es/$1 [L,R=301]
```

([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666899/htaccess-redirect-www-es-to-non-www-es/14667099#comment20501673_14666899))

Comment: That's good practice in general, but would not help with the issue he mentioned. Should be a comment rather than an answer.